# .tracer() in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am working on a python project that involves setting a screen where the turtle can move. This is what the code looks like:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.screen()
window.title("My game")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(800,800)
window.tracer(0)`
```

In the last line I have no clue what the `.tracer(0)` command is doing, and what it means. I would appreciate some help.

I ran the code including and excluding the line `window.tracer(0)`. I didn't see any difference.

Comment: What is does? You should go with documentation how thing works in [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) What exactly last line does [check this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=tracer#turtle.tracer)

Comment: its expected that you would do at least some level of research yourself. Apart from the python docs there are many other sites with tutorials.

Comment: You don't really have enough code for `tracer(0)` to matter one way or the other. It disables the internal update loop so you can run your own update loop and call `turtle.update()` when you want to paint a frame.